# Does anyone know why my tkinter buttons aren't rendering?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is for a python project on GitHub where I'm making a GUI for a Magic 8 Ball simulation. I cant seem to use the .pack() function or my window just loads forever without ever instantiating.

[When created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzYWT.png)

[When I click a button the text appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfYzl.png)

```
window = Tk()
window.configure(bg="black")
window.title("Magic 8 Ball")
Label(window, text="Ask the Magic 8 Ball the question on your mind or enter X to exit: ", bg="black", fg="white")\
    .grid(row=0, column=0)


# Create entry box to type question
entrybox = Entry(window, width=30, bg="white")
entrybox.grid(row=1, column=0)


# Create output box at below buttons
output = Text(window, bg="white", fg="black", width=40, height=5)
output.grid(row=4, column=0)


# Create 4 button: Ask, Clear, Play Again, Quit
button_frame = Frame(window)
button_frame.configure(bg="black")
button_frame.grid(row=2, column=0)

#button_frame.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM)
Button(button_frame, text="Ask", width=10, bg="black", fg="white", command=click).grid(row=2, column=0)
Button(button_frame, text="Clear", width=10, command=clear).grid(row=2, column=1)
Button(button_frame, text="Play Again", width=10,command=repeat).grid(row=3, column=0)
Button(button_frame, text="Quit", width=10, command=close).grid(row=3, column=1)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Strange, I'm on Linux and I can see the button text.

Comment: I'ts an issue with my OS i think, so I'm trying it on a VM

Comment: tkinter on Mojave is a little bit buggy. When the GUI comes up, try manually resizing the window. I'm guessing the text on the buttons will show up when you resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

I think we will need more specifications about your OS and python version. I ran it on Python 3.5.0 and Windows 10 with the result:

[image: Buttons are visible]

So I do not think it is an error in your code. I did have to add in all the functions and import you were missing so what I ran ended up looking like:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
def click():
    print('click')
def clear():
    print('clear')
def repeat():
    print('repeat')
def close():
    print('close')
window.configure(bg="black")
window.title("Magic 8 Ball")
Label(window, text="Ask the Magic 8 Ball the question on your mind or enter X to exit: ", bg="black", fg="white")\
    .grid(row=0, column=0)


# Create entry box to type question
entrybox = Entry(window, width=30, bg="white")
entrybox.grid(row=1, column=0)


# Create output box at below buttons
output = Text(window, bg="white", fg="black", width=40, height=5)
output.grid(row=4, column=0)


# Create 4 button: Ask, Clear, Play Again, Quit
button_frame = Frame(window)
button_frame.configure(bg="black")
button_frame.grid(row=2, column=0)

#button_frame.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM)
Button(button_frame, text="Ask", width=10, bg="black", fg="white", command=click).grid(row=2, column=0)
Button(button_frame, text="Clear", width=10, command=clear).grid(row=2, column=1)
Button(button_frame, text="Play Again", width=10,command=repeat).grid(row=3, column=0)
Button(button_frame, text="Quit", width=10, command=close).grid(row=3, column=1)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Right I apologize, macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and I've run it with Python 2.7 and 3.7

Comment: Have you tried creating the buttons on one line and then calling `.grid()` on a separate line? You would have to use a variable to temporarily store them, but maybe it would help? I'm mostly at a loss because I do not develop on Mac, and also the script runs on my PC without reproducing the error.

Comment: I'm glad it's rendering, it might have something to do with how i obtained python? I saw others were having an issue when getting it through homebrew on Mojave but i tried downloading it from python.org and I'm still having the same issue

Comment: Or maybe you could install a virtual box machine that allows you to develop on Linux or Windows? Do you plan on deploying the application to Mac users?

Comment: Well I'm glad to hear that it's running fine on other systems, this mac is the last I plan to own in the future anyway. I havent used my vm in a while but let me try it

Comment: If you don't need to make it work on Mac then I would just get a virtual box and install another OS on that. I've used https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads before and it's free. You just need to find an .iso file for whatever OS you want (which you can also find for free with enough digging). This would let you have a computer inside your computer that is a different OS that you can develop on! So no need to throw away your old PC to get a new OS

Comment: Thank you for that advice, I'll definitely do that!